# Check log files for file transfer

Tags: mac, logs, file-transfer

I would like if there is a way to capture in a log file all the transfer file activities in a given time period. Let me give you an example. Let's say that on 16 Aug 2017 13:35 I copy/move a file/folder from my Mac to a usb device without giving any special arguments when using the `cp/mv` commands (in any case copying/moving files/folders can be achieved through GUI).

Is there any text file on the Mac which records the activity history (such as copying/moving files/folders)? I would like this text file to include information in a way like:

`16 Aug 2017 13:35 path/to/folderA was copied to /path/to/usb/stick/` or something similar.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?  Your question reads like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Can you [edit] it to include any error messages you're getting or include a statement of the issue you're facing?  Open-ended questions, like this is currently structured, don't really fit well on a Q&A site (see [help/dont-ask]).

Comment: @fsb Tried to reformulate.

Comment: This can be accomplished with DTrace scripts like opensnoop or iosnoop (which run in separate Terminal windows). DTrace is rather a dev tool which requires some expertise than a common day-to-day user tool with some pretty GUI. Even after editing your question it's still unclear what your problem really is.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually use the Terminal command `cp` (copy) or `mv` (move) with the `-v` (for verbose) qualifier to keep a log of what is being copied. Verbose only shows file names, no dates.

You should look at `man cp` and `man mv` for more details.

Ex:

[image]

If you're looking for capturing log data for Finder drags, or disk activity from within apps, I'm not sure how that would be done.